# Feature request for tab indention

Tags: feature-request

Currently 4 spaces have to be typed into the textarea manually to get the 4 space indention for code that spans multiple lines. I am aware of the code snippet feature but there is not always a code snippet that can be **run** as such. If there already exists a better way to do such a thing please let me know. It is hard putting in 4 spaces before every line especially when the snippet is very long.

Comment: @psubsee2003 My question was SO specific and not textarea in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This already exists. Instead of manually indenting every line, you can type the code in normally, select it, and click the "Code Sample" (`{}`) button above the question/answer box. This will indent the whole selection by four spaces per line so that it renders as text.

Comment: Or, select and hit `Ctrl + K` on the keyboard.

Comment: I sometimes have to edit code after I have indented it. At that point, any inserted line has to have spaces typed manually.